# How to reverse print a pattern using java

Tags: java

I write a code that `If num = 8` should show a output as below, but the code do not show that result, could any one help whats my wrong?

```
System.out.printf("Enter number of row for pattern to show : ");
            int num = input.nextInt();

    for(i=num-1;i>0;i--){
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if((i+j)%2==0)
                System.out.print(0);
            else
                System.out.print(1);
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
```

Expected output :

```
10101010
010101
01010
1010
010
10
0
```

Comment: `Reverse print???` How does the string get shorter every time?

Comment: whats the out out with this code?

Comment: Sorry guys, it's just typo. Program is running fine, I just curious about how to get expected output as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few issues with your code preventing it compiling

- You need to declare i and j in the for loops.
- Need convert String num to integer, via `Integer.parseInt(num)`
- -1 is unnecessary in the first for loop (unless you change the continuation condition to `i >= 0` instead of `i > 0`)

Fixing these...

```
for (int i = Integer.parseInt(num); i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(0);
        } else {
            System.out.print(1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This gives a slightly different output, i.e. the original question does not output a line of length 7, it goes from 8 to 6. Also line 6 is 'off by one' This is almost certainly a typo in the original question.

```
Original question        My output

1) 10101010              10101010
2) <= missing =>         0101010
3) 010101                101010     <== mismatch. expected ends in 1
4) 01010                 01010
5) 1010                  1010
6) 010                   010
7) 10                    10
8) 0                     0
```

This can be worked around

```
for (int i = Integer.parseInt(num); i > 0; i--) {
    if (i == 7) {
        continue; // conform to broken question
    }
    if (i == 6) {
        System.out.println("010101"); // conform to broken question
        continue;
    }
    ...
```

Which now gives the expected output

```
10101010
010101
01010
1010
010
10
0
```

Comment: Well, the expected output but not exactly the (presumably incorrect) output shown in the OP's question :)

Comment: Thanks. I get this result also, but the problem is how to get the expected output like shown above.

Comment: I'm unclear what the pattern is in the expected output... Could you explain... it does not appear to be "regular".

Comment: Yeah, i also unclear about it. Just curious whether possible to display the output like this.

Comment: It's the 2nd line that doesn't follow the obvious  pattern.  Could it be a typo in the question?

Comment: I can show from 0 to 1010101010, when the question request for reversing it start from 010101 as shown above. I have no idea whether there is a way to do that or just a mistake for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple changes to your code, and commented what they were. I...

1. declared `Scanner` method called input
2. made `num` of type `int`(rather than `String`)
3. Declared `i` and `j` in your `for` loops
4. fixed the first `for` loop(used to be `i=num-1`, should be `i=num`).

Code shown below:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //created Scanner method
        System.out.printf("Enter number of row for pattern to show : ");
        int num = input.nextInt(); //num should be of type 'int', not String

        for(int i=num; i>0; i--) { //Declared 'i', 'i' should equal 'num', not 'num-1'
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) { //Declared 'j'
                if((i+j)%2==0)
                    System.out.print(0);
                else
                    System.out.print(1);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

And when `num` is 8, you get the output you desired:

```
Enter number of row for pattern to show : 8
10101010
0101010
101010
01010
1010
010
10
0
```

Comment: I know this seems very similar to Adams post, But he used `Integer.parseInt()`, whereas I just declared `num` as  `int`. I also assumed that the output you gave in your question was a typo(two lines in a row started with 0). If this was not a typo please tell me, so I can edit my post.

Comment: @心心傷心 if this answer was helpful to you, please accept it.